# Why do title and author appear more than once?

Tags: formatting, titles, author, journal-publishing

I'm writing a math paper that begins

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{letterpaper} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of Paper}

\author{My Name}

\subjclass[2020]{Primary 11D09, 11D25; Secondary 12D15}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Blah blah blah

\end{abstract}

\newpage


Text and formulas including

\begin{table}

\caption{A Sample of blah blah blah }

\end{table}

\begin{align*}

\end{align*}

\begin{figure}

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{venndiagram.jpg}

\end{center}

\caption{Venn diagram of non-primitive triples for $Set_{53}$ where $(2n-1)=105$}

\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem {A} https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369742/looking-for-references-to-pythagorean-triple-subsets

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

The first page with title, author, abstract, and subject class look like the sample I found from AMS.
(I added \newpage because the \subjclass used to appear in the middle of page 1 just before a table.) Now my concern is that "My Name" also appears on page 2, "Title of Paper" appears on page 3, "My Name" appears on page 4, and so on.

Is this a feature or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that shows your problem and that we can compile. As it is you are saying that your code doesn't work but haven't exhibited your code.

Comment: @Peter Wilson I have added what I think you are asking for. You can omit the table and graphics and bibliography if that helps but need filler to get it to go to multiple pages. What is an. MWE?.

Comment: Your code cannot compile successfully. For instance, it contains two `\begin{table}` statements but no `\end{table}` statements. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mico The 2nd \begin{table} was a copy/paste error and has been corrected here. It was correct in my paper. User Fintan provided a solution.  Thanks for looking out.

Comment: Instead of `\newpage`, you can attach the option `[ht]` to both the table and the figure.  Actually, neither a table nor a figure should be placed below the first-page footnotes, so that's a potential bug.  I have reported it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your objection to the running header on the top of every page?
You can suppress this by adding
`\pagestyle{plain}`
before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged this "journal-publishing", if you are planning to submit your article to the AMS (you are using `amsart`), please remove the `geometry` resetting.

The page width is very important in deciding line breaks and layout of displays.  If you change it, especially to make it wider (as you have done here), if you submit the article to a journal with a narrower page, you run a serious risk of having a copyeditor who is not familiar with the content of your article make different line breaking decisions that may even change the meaning of the affected math expression(s).  Really, only the author knows exactly what is intended; thus the author should make such decisions.

Your question about the repeated author and title as running heads has already been answered.  (Specify `\pagestyle{plain}` to reduce the header/footer information to just the page number.)

The two floats -- `table` and `figure` -- should indeed not appear below the footnotes at the bottom of the first page; this is a "misfeature", and I have reported it to the AMS technical support group.  However, instead of requesting a page break, just add the options `[ht]` to such floats.  That will move them to the next page if there isn't room "here".

Comment: The "geometry" thing was in the sample I downloaded from AMS called "journal.tex" but I have "removed" it with a % sign. It did not change anything so far.